# k-CNF problem reduction to learning- monomials

Tags: monomial-function

I'm studying computational learning and trying to wrap my head around a statement I stumble upon

> A k-CNF function is a function f : {0, 1}
>   n → {0, 1} of the form: f(x1, . . . , xn) = C1 ∧ C2 ∧ . . . ∧ Ct
>   where each clause Ci
>   is of the form ∨k
>   j=1 ℓj and the ℓj s are literals (to get less than k literals, the
>   same literal can appear more than once).

later , assuming k is constant it possible to reduce K-CNF to learning-Monomial.

I assume it can be done with De Morgan's rules

my question is : Am I correct? and how can it be proved ?

**EDIT**
clarification about reduction

> this learning problem can be reduced to learning monomials. That is,
>   you can use the monomial learning algorithm (as is) to solve this
>   problem

Comment: A 1-CNF is a monomial.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi of course you are right , my question is how to prove it for less trivial k (lets say k=3) , I can also transfer k-CNF to k-DNF but again I don't fimilar enough to construct all the step to prove this reduction

Comment: What is the definition of "reduction" in your source?

Comment: I'll edit question to make it more readable

Comment: Thank you.  Meanwhile, I think the trick alluded to is that you can introduce new Boolean variables, one for each possible $k$-term.  Then you learn a monomial in this new set of "features" and finally map back to a $k$-CNF formula.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi sorry for nagging but can you please elaborate few steps so I can accept your answer (you helped me so much till now) and maybe learn how statements of this type may be interpreted in the future

Comment: I'll write up an answer.  Meanwhile, which book are you reading?

Comment: This is a part of series of lectures I take (Intro. to Comp. learning theory ) in my University

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to learn a $2$-CNF over features $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.  There are quadratically many clauses with $2$ literals:

$$ (x_1 \vee x_1), (x_1 \vee \neg x_1), (\neg x_1 \vee \neg x_1), (x_1 \vee x_2), \ldots, (\neg x_4 \vee \neg x_4) \enspace. $$

Some of these clauses are tautologies (e.g., $x_1 \vee \neg x_1$) and you need at most one of them, but the total number is still quadratic.  More generally, for $k$-CNF, the number of clauses is bounded by $(2n)^k$, where $n$ is the number of features.  The factor of $2$ comes from the positive and negative literal.

Introduce a new variable for each possible clause.  A simple way to denote name such variables is to use the clause they correspond to as a subscript:

$$ x_1 \vee \neg x_3 \text{ corresponds to } y_{x_1 \vee \neg x_3} \enspace. $$

This notation makes it clear that we have a bijection.

Then it is a simple matter to associate a monomial in the $y$ variables to a given $k$-CNF formula.  For example,

$$ (x_2 \vee \neg x_3) \wedge (x_4 \vee x_4) $$

corresponds to

$$ y_{x_2 \vee \neg x_3} \wedge y_{x_4 \vee x_4} \enspace. $$

Once a monomial in the $y$ variables is learned, the corresponding $k$-CNF is derived by replacing each $y$ variable with the corresponding clause.

---

In the context of PAC learning, the size of the hypothesis space $H$ determines whether a concept is considered *learnable*.  Specifically, $\log |H|$ has to be polynomial.  For monomials of at most $n$ variables, $|H| = 3^n$, so that $\log|H| = n \log 3$ and all is well.  For $k$-CNF, we get

$$ \log|H| = \log 3^{(2n)^k} = (2n)^k \log 3 \enspace. $$

This is where the fixed-$k$ assumption comes in, because for fixed $k$, $(2n)^k \log 3$ is a polynomial.