# k-CNF formulae and formulae that are not equivalent to them

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I would like to understand the complexity of [$k$-CNF formulae](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535259/k-cnf-problem-reduction-to-learning-monomials).

> For $k\geqslant 1$, can one please give me an example of a formula that is not equivalent to a $k$-CNF formula?